# Showing there exists a polynomial-time algorithm for deciding the existence of a linear classifier

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np, polynomial-time

[image]

For this question I figure we need to define a system of linear inequalities which I thought could be something like this : 
 a1x1 + a2x2 + ... + anxn ≥ b if (x1, x2, ..., xn) ∈ X 
a1x1 + a2x2 + ... + anxn ≤ b if (x1, x2, ..., xn) ∈ Y 
I'm not sure whether this would be correct or how to continue the proof from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the system of inequations having the $a_k$ and $b$ for unknowns.

$$\forall x\in X:\sum_{k=1}^n x_ka_k-b\ge 0,
\\\forall y\in Y:\sum_{k=1}^n y_ka_k-b< 0.$$

This system is made of a polynomial number of equations in $n+1$ unkonwns. By the Linear Feasibility, you can determine if the system has a solution in polynomial time.

And by its definition, a solution does constitute a linear classifier.

Comment: how did you find a and b? @Yves Daoust?

Comment: @Hitriaka: what do you mean ?